# Is there a way to attach the position of one SVG to another?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to build an image where some dots are attached to the border of waves. In theory, I would like the dots to follow the edges of the waves as you scale the page/image.

Any advice would be amazing!

Please take a look at the code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/reveriedesigns/oxyemnu2/

```css
#wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
}

#leftcircle{
  top: 80%;
  left: 20%;
}

#centercircle{
  top: 60%;
  left: 55%;
}

#rightcircle{
  top: 82%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="wave"  viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,160L60,133.3C120,107,240,53,360,58.7C480,64,600,128,720,176C840,224,960,256,1080,224C1200,192,1320,96,1380,48L1440,0L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,224L60,224C120,224,240,224,360,186.7C480,149,600,75,720,53.3C840,32,960,64,1080,96C1200,128,1320,160,1380,176L1440,192L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,96L40,106.7C80,117,160,139,240,170.7C320,203,400,245,480,256C560,267,640,245,720,218.7C800,192,880,160,960,165.3C1040,171,1120,213,1200,234.7C1280,256,1360,256,1400,256L1440,256L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>

  </svg>

  <svg class="circle" id="centercircle">
     <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="circle" id="leftcircle" >
      <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="circle" id="rightcircle">
      <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: One solution would be putting the circles in the same svg element as the waves. Then using Javascript you can calculate the position of the point on the wave and you draw the circle there. In order to calculate the position of a point on a path you can use the `getPointAtLength()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use one svg tag unless there is good reason to use more than one?

svg (scalar vector graphics) are designed to scale perfectly as you scale the page.

So I took your circle elements and put them inside the waves svg element, and now everything stays in place?

Check out this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/r8c07h1g/5/

[image]

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#background {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgb(76, 72, 143);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76, 72, 143, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 53, 108, 1) 35%, rgba(36, 35, 72, 1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76, 72, 143, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 53, 108, 1) 35%, rgba(36, 35, 72, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(76, 72, 143, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 53, 108, 1) 35%, rgba(36, 35, 72, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(76, 72, 143, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 53, 108, 1) 35%, rgba(36, 35, 72, 1) 100%);
}
#wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
} 
#leftcircle{
  top: 80%;
  left: 20%;
}
#centercircle{
  top: 60%;
  left: 55%;
}
#rightcircle{
  top: 82%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <svg id="wave"  viewBox="0 0 1440 320">     
    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,160L60,133.3C120,107,240,53,360,58.7C480,64,600,128,720,176C840,224,960,256,1080,224C1200,192,1320,96,1380,48L1440,0L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,224L60,224C120,224,240,224,360,186.7C480,149,600,75,720,53.3C840,32,960,64,1080,96C1200,128,1320,160,1380,176L1440,192L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>
    <path stroke="#48609D" fill="#454E88" fill-opacity="0.7" d="M0,96L40,106.7C80,117,160,139,240,170.7C320,203,400,245,480,256C560,267,640,245,720,218.7C800,192,880,160,960,165.3C1040,171,1120,213,1200,234.7C1280,256,1360,256,1400,256L1440,256L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>

    <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="325" cy="49" r="10"/>
    <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="785" cy="37" r="10"/>
    <circle stroke="#48609D" fill="#D2D4E4" fill-opacity="0.4" cx="940" cy="155" r="10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @alex-l . That was exactly what I was looking for. I'm just beginning to play with SVGS and did not think to play with the x and y coordinates.

Comment: My pleasure. SVGs are awesome! Have fun! And post questions when you get stuck :)